# Discord bot API Limit

Tags: discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.typing = False
intents.presences = False
intents.messages = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".", intents=intents)

UYGUN_KANALLAR_KATEGORISI_ID = ""
ARA_KATEGORISI_ID = ""
BILIM_KATEGORILERI_ID = {"Fizik": "ID", "Kimya": "ID", "Matematik": "ID", "Biyoloji": "ID"}

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return

    if str(message.channel.category_id) == UYGUN_KANALLAR_KATEGORISI_ID:
        await message.channel.edit(name=f"help-{message.channel.name.split('-')[1]}-{message.author.name}")
        await message.channel.edit(category=bot.get_channel(int(ARA_KATEGORISI_ID)))
        await message.channel.send("Sorunuz hangi alanda? Fizik için 1' e basın, Kimya için 2'ye basın, Matematik için 3'e basın, Biyoloji için 4'e basın")

    elif str(message.channel.category_id) == ARA_KATEGORISI_ID:
        response_dict = {"1": "Fizik", "2": "Kimya", "3": "Matematik", "4": "Biyoloji"}
        if message.content in response_dict:
            await message.channel.edit(category=bot.get_channel(int(BILIM_KATEGORILERI_ID[response_dict[message.content]])))

    await bot.process_commands(message)


@bot.command(name="kapat")
async def close(ctx):
    if "help-" in ctx.message.channel.name and ctx.message.author.name in ctx.message.channel.name:
        await ctx.message.channel.edit(name=f"help-{ctx.message.channel.name.split('-')[1]}")
        await ctx.message.channel.edit(category=bot.get_channel(int(UYGUN_KANALLAR_KATEGORISI_ID)))


bot.run("TOKEN")
```

The channel that has been moved to the appropriate channels needs to become usable again, but API Rate Limit is constantly stuck.

how can i solve this problem?

Even though I put a wait time on each code, the result is still the same.

Comment: Depends on where you’re hosting the bot, you can’t do anything about a rate limit but wait. Usually takes around a few hours to 24 hours

Comment: If you are hosting your bot on sites like repl.it there is not much you can do without changing hosts.

Answer (score 0):

Discord has a rate limit of 5 actions per guild and per second (for non interaction based commands). Channel edits and similar stuff are included in that. Based on the code, it would easily exceed that. Without knowing the goal of the project, it's hard to say what a solution would be. But in general, you should try using interaction based commands wherever you can if you are having issues related to rate limits.

For starters, you can try to use a command to trigger the bot and send an interaction response with buttons rather than to send a message telling them to input a number.